# VB.NET Columns separated by spaces and I need value of 9th column

Tags: vb.net

I'm relatively new to VB.NET and am wondering how I can get the value of the ninth column. Columns are separated by spaces.

The value im getting will be added to a int so say `int = 2` then the column is `32` then the int will be `34`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : `Dim col9 as Integer = Integer.Parse(s.Split(New Char() {" "c})(8))`

I am splitting the string with spaces and finding the 9th column. If you want 32nd column, instead of 8 you should use 31.